# How to customize reorderHandle in drag mode in angular typescript or how to hide it

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

```
<RadListView row="0" [items]="Array" itemReorder="true" (itemReordered)="groupReordered($event)" reorderMode="Drag">
```

how to hide default drag handle in ios or how to customize it

Comment: Please help me asap

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample playgroud for you [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=eE4rml&v=2).

To customise the recordhandle, you need to set that in item-template for listview like below

```
<RadListView class="list-group" [items]="countries" (itemReordered)="onItemReordered($event)"
        itemReorder="true" reorderMode="Drag" style="height:1250px">
        <ng-template let-country="item">
            <FlexboxLayout flexDirection="row" class="list-group-item">
                <ReorderHandle  verticalAlignment="center">
                    <Image [src]="country.imageSrc" class="thumb img-circle"></Image>
                </ReorderHandle>

                <Label [text]="country.name" class="list-group-item-heading"
                    verticalAlignment="center" style="width: 60%"></Label>
            </FlexboxLayout>

        </ng-template>
    </RadListView>
```

by default in ios, a reorder handle is displayed at the right side of the item. But in the example above you can drag by image. Also if you want to `hide` that then do not pass anything in `ReorderHandle`.